# R read.zoo error for incorrect date format

Tags: r, xts, zoo

I have a data that has one date column and 10 other columns.
The date column has the format of 199010.
so it's yyyymm. 
It seems like that zoo/xts requires that the date has days info in it.
Is there any way to address this issue?

hier ist my data

```
structure(list(Date = 198901:198905, NoDur = c(5.66, -1.44, 5.51, 
5.68, 5.32)), .Names = c("Date", "NoDur"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
5L))


data<-read.zoo("C:/***/data_port.csv",sep=",",format="%Y%m",header=TRUE,index.column=1,colClasses=c("character",rep("numeric",1)))
```

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: sorry, what is that? It doesn't seem to answer my question directly. I lost myself while reading it.

Comment: The link does not answer your question. It shows you how to ask a question.  The key requirement is that posters must provide a reproducible example.  That which means anyone can simplyh copy it to the clipboard from your question and paste it into their R session without additional work and that will run your code and reproduce  the problem.

Comment: hope this helps. My original csv data looks like the above table. I can't get it to read because of the Date structure.

Comment: In this case dput would not be used since the input is supposed to be data to be read into read.zoo.  See answer for how you would specify it reproducibly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code has these problems:

- the data is space separated but the code specifies that it is comma separated
- the data does not describe dates since there is no day but the code is using the default of dates
- the data is not provided in reproducible form. Note how one can simply copy the data and code below and paste it into R without any additional work.

Try this:

```
Lines <- "Date   NoDur
198901  5.66
198902  -1.44
198903  5.51
198904  5.68
198905  5.32
"

library(zoo)
read.zoo(text = Lines, format = "%Y%m", FUN = as.yearmon, header = TRUE, 
       colClasses = c("character", NA))
```

The above converts the index to `"yearmon"` class which probably makes most sense here but it would alternately be possible to convert it to `"Date"` class by using `FUN = function(x, format) as.Date(as.yearmon(x, format))` in place of the
`FUN` argument above.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your work! This solved my problem. I guess the proper Date should have year, month and days. Since my data doesn't provide "days" information. It makes a bit hard to read. But your approach is perfectly fine. Thank you again.